# JavaScript Failed to execute 'drawImage'

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas, drawimage

Ok so I'm creating a game with JavaScript Canvas Elements and such. I've been able to load in TONS of Images, but on a select few, JavaScript replies with Errors such as

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': No function was found that matched the signature provided.

Which makes NO SENSE at all, because the same code works in other places!?!

Here is an example I have in my code:

```
board.drawImage(document.getElementById("player_explode"), this.x, this.y);
```

Inside of an objects method, `Player.die()`, respectively.

Does anyone know why this behaviour is coming about? I'm getting very frustrated about it...

Here is a [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/v3qsM/34/) to demonstrate, alonside all the code.
`Player.die()` is located on `line[242]`.

Comment: Have you checked that all your image elements have finished loading before you try to draw them?

Comment: @kybernetikos Well I just editted it so that the images were all visible in the `.html`, but for some reason it doesn't show up there as well. Is there a limit on the amount of `<img>` that can be loaded in a `.html` file? You can see all the loaded images here: [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/v3qsM/37/)

Comment: I got this error because I was trying to load a corrupted image.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The problem was the way that I was loading my Images, I should've been doing:

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = "imagesource.jpg";
```

But instead I was get the elements by id from the `document` page.

Resources:

[Explanation on loading images](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/preloading-and-the-javascript-image-object/#.)

[Explanation on how html loads images](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images.asp)

Answer (score 4):

you should wait all elements load,so do like this:

```
window.onload=function(){
       board.drawImage(document.getElementById("player_explode"), this.x, this.y);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For people in 2021 learning React, you have to call the `context.drawImage()` in the `img.onload` or nothing will be shown on the canvas! Here is a real world working example:

```
useEffect(() => {
    canvasRef.current.width = mapXYWH.w * UNIT
    canvasRef.current.height = mapXYWH.h * UNIT
    const context = canvasRef.current.getContext("2d")

    map.map(o => {
        const img = new Image(o.width*UNIT,o.height*UNIT)
        img.src = o.normal
        img.onload = () =>
            context.drawImage(img, (o.x-mapXYWH.x)*UNIT, (o.y-mapXYWH.y)*UNIT)
    })
}, [map, mapXYWH])
```

See also: [React -- Canvas Won't Draw Image](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39908575/5290519)