# React -- Canvas Won't Draw Image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, canvas

Struggling a bit here.  If I'm just filling or doing anything else to the canvas - no issue.  I get the div without the external image.  Tried local image file as well as URL...  Thanks!

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';

export default class CanvasCreator extends Component {

componentDidMount() {
    this.updateCanvas();
}

updateCanvas() {
    const ctx = this.refs.canvas.getContext('2d');

    var imageObj1 = new Image();
    imageObj1.src = 'https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/d7/b3/cf/d7b3cfe04c2dc44400547ea6ef94ba35.jpg'
    ctx.drawImage(imageObj1,0,0);

}
render() {
    return (


        <canvas ref="canvas" width={300} height={300}> </canvas>

    );
 }
};
```

Answer (score 19):

You are missing the onload method. This will work for you:

```
   updateCanvas() {
    const ctx = this.refs.canvas.getContext('2d');

    var imageObj1 = new Image();
    imageObj1.src = 'https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/d7/b3/cf/d7b3cfe04c2dc44400547ea6ef94ba35.jpg'
 imageObj1.onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(imageObj1,0,0);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me in order to work was also necessary to add the width and height!

Example:

```js
imageObj1.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(imageObj1, 0, 0, 500, 500)
}
```