# GET http://localhost:8601/[object%20Object] 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, mit-scratch

I'm trying to import tensorflow models in to my program in JS, and I'm getting a `GET http://localhost:8601/[object%20Object] 404 (Not Found)` error. My code is as follows

```
importModel() {
        console.log("import model start");
        //from https://github.com/googlecreativelab/teachablemachine-community/blob/master/libraries/image/README.md
        //also https://medium.com/jspoint/javascript-promises-and-async-await-as-fast-as-possible-d7c8c8ff0abc
        const url = "<URL>";
        const modelUrl = url + "model.json";
        const metadataUrl = url + "metadata.json";
        return tmImage.load(modelUrl, metadataUrl)
            .then((model) => {
                console.log(model);
                maxPredictions = model.getTotalClasses();
                return model;
            });
    }
    getXCoord(args, util) {
        //A1 or A2 returns 0
        //B1 or B2 returns 1
        this.importModel()
            .then(model => {
                //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22430671/javascript-failed-to-execute-drawimage
                var webcamImage = new Image();
                webcamImage.src = this.runtime.renderer._allDrawables[util.target.drawableID];
                const prediction = model.predict(webcamImage);
                console.log(prediction);
            });
    }
```

The program is a Scratch GUI run in localhost, which is why it shows localhost 8601.

Comment: `this.runtime.renderer._allDrawables[util.target.drawableID]` is an object (or an array), the image expects `src` being a string.

Comment: @Teemu how do I convert my image to a string then, given I'm trying to use an image-based model?